# “log in ” website with requests and threading “python”

Tags: python

I want to login to website but using threading and see many tutorial and can't find my situation

```
import requests

 data = open("data.txt","r").read().splitlines()
 #loding the username and password
 url="example.com/login"

for row in data:
    #for each row in the data to login with it
    datanow=row.split(":")
    user=datanow[0]
    password=datanow[1]

    headers={
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Length": "159",
    "Host": "sso.godaddy.com",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Accept": "application/json",        
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    data={
      "LOG_USER_IN":"true",
       "user_name": user ,
       "password": password
        }

     r=requests.post(url , timeout=5 , headers = headers,data=data)
     #printing the reaspose
     print(r)
```

that make the login very slow but i want for example login 10 times at the same time or 20 at the same time how can i make that is the threading is't my perfect choice ??

Comment: Which python Version are you using

Comment: Just use multi thread or multi process module

Comment: use python 3  PDHide
can you give me a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the threading module,

thread.start() starts the thread

```
import requests
import threading
from datetime import datetime

 data = open("data.txt","r").read().splitlines()
 #loding the username and password
 url="example.com/login"

for row in data:
    #for each row in the data to login with it
    datanow=row.split(":")
    user=datanow[0]
    password=datanow[1]

    headers={
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Length": "159",
    "Host": "sso.godaddy.com",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Accept": "application/json",        
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    data={
      "LOG_USER_IN":"true",
       "user_name": user ,
       "password": password
        }

    threads = []
    def thread_function(url, headers, data):
        print(datetime.now())
        print(requests.post(url, timeout=5, headers=headers, data=data))

    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(url,headers,data,))
    threads.append(x)
    x.start()
```

Comment: how can set number of workers ? 
for example set 10 or 20 to work at the same time

Comment: Create a loop and call thread .start() 20 times

Comment: in the given example say you have 20 users in the data file , it will send 20 users

Comment: as the x.start() is in the for row in data, see the time printed to know when the reqeust was send. Python is not a pure multi thread languge so there will tiny millisec difference

Comment: If the answer is helpful , please accept it by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: thank you sir about your help